# The request failed with HTTP Status 403: Forbidden when calling a web service

Tags: web-services, iis, c#-4.0

I have a problem when calling a method from an external web service. 
The error returned is as follows:

> The request failed with HTTP Status 403

My application is deployed using ClickOnce technology. The strange thing is that when I call service (test the code) on my development machine and additionally in test environment (IIS 6, Windows 2003 Server) everything is fine. 
Unfortunately when application is in production environment (Windows 2003 Server, IIS 6) the error is returned. 
I don't use a service reference to call a web service, instead I use a proxy class generated from wsdl.exe application. Can someone please help me.

**EDIT:**
I noticed that I can't even access wsdl file using web browser from that production server. **This production server is also in different domain.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. It seems that the company that owns the external web service has some kind of access list with IP addresses allowed to access this web service